# Write Arraylist of data to excel using java

Tags: java

I want to write to data which contains ArrayList of String to excel using java.
When i am doing only the first data only writing to excel.remaining data is not.

```
public class ExcelGenerator {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, HPSFException, IOException, SQLException, NestableException
    {
        ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
          arrlist.add("14");
          arrlist.add("7");
          arrlist.add("39");
          arrlist.add("40");

          /* For Loop for iterating ArrayList */
          System.out.println("For Loop");
          for (int counter = 0; counter < arrlist.size(); counter++) {            
              System.out.println(arrlist.get(counter));         
          }   


        HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();
        File f=new File("D:/Test/test.xls");
        GeericExcelGenerator gl=new GeericExcelGenerator("Test",workbook);
        FileOutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(f);
        gl.generate(outputStream,arrlist);

    }

    public void generate(OutputStream outputStream,ArrayList arrlist) throws SQLException, IOException, NestableException 
    {
        try 
        {
            int currentRow = 0;
            for (int counter = 0; counter < arrlist.size(); counter++) {    

                HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(currentRow);
                System.out.println("Description is"+arrlist.get(counter));

                String c=(String) arrlist.get(counter);
                int i=0;
                HSSFCell cell = HSSFCellUtil.createCell(row, i, null);
                cell.setCellValue(c);

                 i++;
                workbook.write(outputStream);
                currentRow++;
                currentRow++;
            }
        }catch(IOException  e)
        {}
        finally {
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use the formatter in your IDE? It will make your code easier to read.

Comment: If you program isn't working, I would not ignore exceptions, but rather print them as they might be trying to tell you something.

Comment: Where does the `sheet` variable suddely come from? I don't see it initialized anywhere. This cant' compile.

Answer (score 3):

Try below solution may due to your initialization "i" variable

```
public void generate(OutputStream outputStream, ArrayList arrlist)
        throws SQLException, IOException, NestableException {
    try {
        int currentRow = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < arrlist.size(); counter++) {

            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(currentRow);
            System.out.println("Description is" + arrlist.get(counter));

            String c = (String) arrlist.get(counter);

            HSSFCell cell = HSSFCellUtil.createCell(row, i, null);
            cell.setCellValue(c);

            i++;
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            currentRow++;
            currentRow++;

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    } finally {
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Or you can check your implmentation with below example
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/examples/HSSFReadWrite.java